# Firebase domain not whitelisted

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My React app hosted on firebase is erroring on;

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=...
```

telling me that the domain unauthorized. I'm calling the app from custom domain I've added under authentication=>settings=>authorized domains. I've been through other SO posts and can't seem to understand what's wrong. I'm only using Email/Password sign in provider.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN : Domain not whitelisted by project",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN : Domain not whitelisted by project",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question should include details on how someone can reproduce this as you see it, including all code and procedures you have in place.  Also read about creating a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) to make it easier for someone to help.

Comment: @DougStevenson I was able to fix it. Apparently, the placeholder they have on the input field for the domain is wrong. It says myapp.com, yet if you don't add 'www' you'll still be getting the error